# Display server json data in bootstrap datatable as popup modal

Tags: php, json, database, datatables

[image]

This is my Db Table.i want to display the table value in bootstrap datatable on modal popup.

Main.html

```
<a href="#myModal" id="custId" data-toggle="modal" data-id="special-fy" class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h5 class="modal-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Stone Details</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="fetched-data">
                    <table id="example" class="table tab_header table-bordered cmntbl" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>COUNTRY</th>
                           </tr>
                    </thead>
                    </table>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my jquery like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "ajax": {
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : "data.php",
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                return json.data;
            }       
            }
    });
 });
```

and my data.php like:

```
$sql_sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `testt2`");
$array = array();
$array['data'] = array();

while($res_sel = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_sel)){
    $array['data'][] = $res_sel;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

**Its all working fine, But i want to pass the table header (ID,NAME,COUNTRY) dynamically from data.php with json array and these column name, i want to display in datatable.**

Answer (score 0):

To get that data, you'd need to extract the field headers from mysqli, such as

```
$columns = mysqli_fetch_fields($sql_sel);

$attributes = array();
foreach ($columns as $column)
{
    $attributes[] = $column->name;
}
```

This will put the column headers into the `$attributes` array and you can add that data in whatever way makes the most sense for your frontend.